# Concatenating noneType and string value columns (pandas dataframes) results in "NaN"

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nonetype

I'm trying to concatenate two columns and the second column has a few noneType values. When I try to concatenate both the columns with the noneType values, the resulting column results in "NaN".

I tried to look around to see if I could find questions on this behavior, but I wasn't able to.

Here's what the table looked before concatenation:

[image]

Here's my code to join the two columns after my modifications:

```
new_table["name"] = new_table[0] + new_table[1]
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Why is does concatenation result in "NaN" and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Please share code and data as text in the post itself, not as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900. Have you read the Pandas docs? _and how can I fix it?_ There's nothing to fix, `NaN` has a purpose. Speaking of, why were you using `None` in the DataFrame?

Comment: Noted for the images. I have read the pandas docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html, but I couldn't find an explanation for this behavior. NaN has a function, but is unclear why the string object '+' noneType results in NaN. Since the result is NaN, as opposed to just the data from column one as a summing operation would suggest, I wanted to know how to "fix" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple fix would be to replace None with empty string:

```
new_table["name"] = new_table[0] + new_table[1].fillna('')
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. But is there a reason why concatenation between noneTypes and strings works this way?

Comment: Python does not allow concatenation between `str` and any other types (including `NoneType`). Pandas catches the `TypeError` and falls back to `NaN`. The burden is on you to tell Pandas how to deal with missing values, to avoid silent failure.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["K.", "Mbappe"], ["N.", np.nan]])
print (df)
```

Output:

```
    0       1  
0  K.  Mbappe  
1  N.     NaN  


df['Name'] = df[0].str.cat(df[1], na_rep='')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    0       1      Name
0  K.  Mbappe  K.Mbappe
1  N.     NaN        N.
```

It is the same approach as ypnos proposed, using Series str.cat function instead.

Comment: A helpful addition to my answer, as `str.cat` is more powerful than plain str concatenation.

Comment: Thank you @Ponx. Is there a reason str.cat is more powerful?